# XUNIT issue: reference project with unit testing class library

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, coverlet

I have a solution with two projects and two class library with unit tests code for each project.

- Middleware
- Middleware.UnitTest
- WebApi
- WebApi.UnitTest

In the WebApi Project I added as Project Reference the Middleware project because is necessary in the process. When I Execute the unit tests for Middleware.UnitTest this is what I get:

[middleware unit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cERQ.png)

but when I execute the WebApi.UnitTests the process try to execute also the Middleware unit test and the result is 0% of code coverage and is not real because the unit test exist. Im not sure what I need to do to avoid that or add a kind of reference to execute also the Middleware unit test when I execute the WebApi.Unit test

[WebApi unit tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU5pm.png)

I cant delete the project reference, I tried to add references of the unit test projects in the web api project but doesn't work, I searched for all google and I didn't find anything.